# How to avoid the last pod being killed on automatic node scale down in AKS

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

We are using Azure AKS v1.17.9 with auto-scaling both for pods (using HorizontalPodAutoscaler) and for nodes. Overall it works well, but we have seen outages in some cases. We have some deployments where minReplicas=1 and maxReplicas=4. Most of the time there will only be one pod running for such a deployment. In some cases where the auto-scaler has decided to scale down a node, the last remaining pod has been killed. Later a new pod is started on another node, but this means an outage.

I would have expected the auto-scaler to first create a new pod running on another node (bringing the number of replicas up to the allowed value of 2) and then scaling down the old pod. That would have worked without downtime. As it is it kills first and asks questions later.

Is there a way around this except the obvious alternative of setting minReplicas=2 (which increases the cost as all these pods are doubled, needing additional VMs)? And is this expected, or is it a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In some cases where the auto-scaler has decided to scale down a node, the last remaining pod has been killed. Later a new pod is started on another node, but this means an outage.

For this reason, you should always have at least 2 replicas for `Deployment` in a production environment. And you should use [Pod Anti-Affinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#inter-pod-affinity-and-anti-affinity) so that those two pods are not scheduled to the same [Availability Zone](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/availability-zones/az-overview#availability-zones). E.g. if there is network problems in one Availability Zone, your app is still available.

It is common to have at least 3 replicas, one in each Availability Zone, since cloud providers typically has 3 Availability Zones in each [Region](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/availability-zones/az-overview#regions) - so that you *can* use inter-zone traffic which is cheaper than cross-zone traffic, typically.

You can always use fewer replicas to save cost, but it is a trade-off and you get worse availability.

Comment: I know that. We do have properly configured redundancy for important pods in production, but I want to know if this can be avoided without that extra cost. After all if a new version is deployed K8s takes care to start a new pod first before it kills the old. There is never an outage. The same could take place here. I'd like to know if we have missed some configuration to make it happen or if this is as good as it gets, plus if it should be considered a bug or normal behavior.

Comment: Ah, you want to **cordon and drain** the node on scale-down. That should be done according to the AKS doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/scale-cluster ...sounds like you say that feature does not work as promised? The management of nodes is handled by the cloud-provider. You refer to both HorizontalPodAutoscaler and Node autoscaling.

Comment: I think it is cordoning and draining, the problem is that the pod in question is killed before a similar pod is started somewhere else. AKS uses the HorizontalPodAutoscaler (which I think is standard?) for scaling pods and custom features for scaling nodes. Both work, but when it removes a node and starts to drain it there is no wait for the pods to start elsewhere before they are killed.

Comment: This issue describes the problem you ask about, it currently seems that you need at least 2 replicas to avoid downtime. https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/issues/1298

Comment: Thanks, that answers my question. Can you copy the link to your answer, please? That makes it easier for others to find it.